# Use jQuery to make element on page modal (not dialog)

Tags: jquery

I'm fairly new to jQuery, so hopefully this isn't too tough. I'll try to stick to a simple example.

Let's assume I have a web page with a div on it (could be other elements such as img, span, etc). When the user hovers over that div, I'd like the div to remain unchanged, but have an overlay applied to everything else so the rest is grayed out. So essentially it would make this div look like it was modal (similar to a modal dialog). I'd want the div to remain in the same location, have the same background color, etc.

I've found examples of doing a modal dialog, but it always centers in the screen. The functionality would work if I could leave the element in the same place. Any ideas?

Thanks!
Jim

Comment: A modal dialog doesn't have to be in the centre, so if you've found examples of code for modals you just have to remove the part that sets the position. (Having said that, berry_lthird's answer indicates how to implement your requirement.)

Answer (score 3):

I chose to look at it this way.

http://jsfiddle.net/uEwry/2/

1. Create a class to detect what elements should trigger the modal effect.
2. When moused over clone the element and trigger the modal effect
3. Place the cloned element over the existing element
4. On mouseout of the cloned element undo the effect and remove the clone

```
.gomodal { border: 1px dotted red; background: white; }
.modal { border: 1px solid black; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; }
#grayout { background: lightgray; opacity: .8; display: none; position: fixed; }


$('.gomodal').mouseover(function() {
    var cloned = $(this)
        .clone()
        .addClass('modal')
        .css('top', $(this).offset().top)
        .css('left', $(this).offset().left); 
    $('body').append(cloned);
    $('#grayout').css('height', $(document).height()).css('width', $(document).width()).fadeIn();
});

$('body').on('mouseout', '.modal', function() {
    $('#grayout').fadeOut();
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is close. The only remaining issue is that I can't be sure the div has a background color specified. If I remove the background color from .gomodal in your example, then the div gets grayed out like everything else. Is there a way around this?

Comment: No, I don't think so. You can't poke holes in the gray shadow. Nor can you tell the cloned elements to be transparent except for the gray shadow. I do not think you will find any solutions without this limitation.

Comment: Cool thanks for the response, one more quick related question. Is there a way I can traverse up the dom to find out which parent element the div is getting it's background color from? So for example if I could figure out that the div is showing through the yellow from the body tag, then I could temporarily assign yellow to the div for the duration of the hover. Does that make sense?

Comment: yeah, I think that is possible. you may want to ask that in another SO question. It actually just occurred to me that you could use transparent borders to get the 'hole' effect. See this SO question with +6 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270034/efficient-html-div-with-hole-in-it

Answer (score 1):

When you say "grayed out", do you mean like a "shadow box"? That is, a shade that's laid over all the other elements on the page?

If that's the case, then create a div that is absolutely positioned over the entire body with an opacity setting to semi-transparent. Then give that div a z-index style above everything else, and set it's display style to "none". This will serve as your "shadow box".

When the user interacts with your target div, change it's z-index style to higher than the shadow box div, then set your shadow box display style to "block". Do the reverse when the user has completed their interaction.

Let me know if this is what you were looking for and if you need a code example.